# How to banish Blender's pesky 3d cursor?

Tags: python, hide, blender, shortcut

I make darkly atmospheric scenes in the Python-based 3d design program 'Blender'. The problem is, as I'm moving around, the 3d cursor (an icon like a bizarre, tiny, red & white life-saving ring!) keeps floating into view & shattering the whole illusion.

I've almost devised a keyboard shortcut that can zip this annoyance out of view... (If you're familiar with Blender, it uses operator `wm.context_set_enum` with Context Attribute `space_data.cursor_location` & then offers co-ordinates eg. `0,0,1000`). Python seems to *almost* accept this placement but  chokes on the 3rd expression

> ValueError: bpy_struct: item.attr=val: sequences of dimension 0 should contain 3 items, not 8

In what form does Python want those `xyz` coordinates? I've given up guessing because I can't see a pattern in the (strangely informative!) rejection & fear specialist syntax is required.

Comment: did you check [this(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=REtg8iK0zv8) video? They create a simple python script!

Comment: Thanks ZF007, I may look that up tomorrow (when my strength returns!) I'm afraid I'm very graphically oriented however... I've done great things in SynthMaker but pure code terrifies me, stuff like the Python I've been wrestling today. I also detect that a script needs some work to integrate into the Blender workflow. Man, I just so want to get back to making pretty pictures! :-(

Comment: That sounds a lot of history my friend. unfortunatly, I can't help you with that. What I do can is letting you know that learning python goes like learning to read and write in English in a kind of almost child's-play and easy understandable manner... GL.

Comment: A location property is a list of three values x,y,z. You can use `cursor_location = (0,0,1000)` or `cursor_location.z = 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Behold a kinder shortcut key for you sir:  at user pref / input / 3dview / 3dview global,, click [add new] below. Inside use (without quote) "wm.context_toggle" with "space_data.show_only_render" ; put your key

3d cursor = [ [ [ GONE! ] ] ]  Also grid / xyz axis / object origin/, also cameras & light (not ther action) =gone. ! Other object can include if you nonrender these object ( outliner shift f9)

Now sir return to your xlnt creation ,  & why be swayed by that complexmachine if  so painful to you ?

respectful ghant